# Recognize the type of an attribute of a generic type?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

Is there a way to use the type of the attribute of a generic for a type hint?

Being new to typing things, I am having trouble formulating my question with the appropriate terms, but I think this code snippet illustrates what I try to do.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[int, str])


class GenericThing(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, thing: T):
        self.thing = thing

    def get_the_thing(self) -> T:
        return self.thing


GenericThingType = TypeVar("GenericThingType", bound=GenericThing)


class GenericContainer(Generic[GenericThingType]):
    def __init__(self, things: list[GenericThingType]):
        self.things = things

    def set_the_thing(self, new):
        # new is of type Any, but isn't it implicitly of type T?
        self.things[0].thing = new


class IntegerThing(GenericThing[int]):
    pass


class IntegerContainer(GenericContainer[IntegerThing]):
    pass


x = IntegerContainer([])
x.set_the_thing("a")  # Mypy, why are you not complaining here?
```

My workaround is to make the container a generic of both `IntegerThing` and `int`:

```py
...

class GenericContainer(Generic[GenericThingType, T]):
    ...
    def set_the_thing(self, new: T):

...
class IntegerContainer(GenericContainer[IntegerThing, int]):
...

x.set_the_thing("a")  # incompatible type "str", expected "int"
```

This works fine, but isn't redundant since the type of `new` could be inferred from `IntegerThing`?

What I am looking for is something like:

```py
    def set_the_thing(self, new: GenericThingType.thing):
```

but this raises a `NameError`: "GenericThingType.thing" is not defined.

Is my workaround the only option or am I failing to find what I am looking for in mypy docs? If not, is it something missing from mypy or is it a code smell hinting that my use of generics is inappropriate? In my real life example, I end with a long lists of arguments to my `Generic[]`s.

Comment: 1. Python is not java, we don't do "getters" and "setters" - please use a property. 2. Mypy doesn't read minds, so it doesn't know that those "get" and "set" methods are supposed to be connected to each other - mypy doesn't guess. 3. I don't play much with mypy, but why do you have a separate `GenericThingType` and not just use `GenericThing` directly? A class is a type. Instantiated class (unless a metaclass) is not a type - i.e. `something: MyClass = MyClass(args_here)` is a normal typehint

Comment: you did not add type hints for `set_the_thing`

Comment: @h4z3 I never worked with java and do not setters and getters instead properties: I tried to produce a MWE but I realize it probably wasn't as good as I hoped. The question really was about mypy use of generics.

Comment: You still didn't reply why you try to make GenericThingType instead of using GenericThing directly. They are literally the same typehint-wise. It will still be double-generic but it will make more sense reading

Comment: I think if you use GenericThing directly, you can make it `class GenericContainer(Generic[GenericThing[T]]):` and then you'll be able to use `T` as typehint more naturally

Comment: `class GenericContainer(Generic[GenericThing[T]]):`: "Free type variable expected in Generic[...]" and `class IntegerContainer(GenericContainer[IntegerThing]):`: `"GenericContainer" expects no type arguments, but 1 given`

Answer (score 3):

> new is of type Any, but isn't it implicitly of type T?

No, it isn't. mypy has no idea what type it's supposed to be.
Moreover, from the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html):

> A function without any types in the signature is dynamically typed. The body of a dynamically typed function is not checked statically, and local variables have implicit Any types

So when you don't have types in your signature, the function is *completely ignored* as far as type checking goes.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T")

class Person(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.age: int = 22

    def grow_up(self, x: T) -> bool:
        return True

p = Person[str]()
p.grow_up(5)
```

This example gives a proper warning like it should:

```
$ mypy example3.py 
example3.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "grow_up" of "Person" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My sortof MWE was not understandable enough. My question was about generics of generics and whether the "first level generic" (T) could be inferred in a "second level generic (GenericContainerType) or if I have to make it explicitely a Generic of both GenericThingType *and* T. I am looking for something like `def method(self, arg: GenericThingType.some_attribute)`